# Load price phtml file in magento2

Tags: php, magento2

I have listed some products in my custom home page template.

I have tried to get price html in home page but its not working.

In magento 1.9 below code is used to load price template

```
 $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
      $productBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_price');
      echo $productBlock->getPriceHtml($_product);
```

How to load this price template in magento 2

Comment: Please check below link for solution [http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142894/load-price-phtml-file-in-magento2](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142894/load-price-phtml-file-in-magento2)